# Better pattern for multi-listener notifications with `gevent.event.Event`?

Tags: python, gevent

I've found that most of the time when I use `gevent.event.Event`, my code looks something like this:

```
old_event = self.some_event
self.some_event = Event()
old_event.set()
```

With the listeners looking something like:

```
while 1:
    self.some_event.wait()
    … do stuff …
```

Is this the “right way to do it”? Or is there a better way to notify multiple listeners of a recurring event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can also `clear()` the event.

```
event.set()
event.clear()
```

This will notify the listeners that are currently waiting for the event, but the listeners that are started to wait() later will be blocked until the next call to `set()`.

Comment: *facepalm* Yes, that is quite obviously the right thing to do. Thanks.

Comment: Calling event.clear() makes it impossible to detect timed out event.wait().

Why event.wait simply returns instead of raising exception when it was timed out?